# Is every contractible open bounded domain in $\mathbb R^{2n}$ symplecomorphic to a star-shaped domain?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology

In Hofer & Zehnder's book "Symplectic Invariants and Hamiltonian Dynamics" (Page 99) they present an example of a star shaped domain (bounded, with smooth boundary) in the shape of a "Bordeaux bottle" which is not symplectomorphic to a convex domain.

In similar spirit, I ask, is there an open bounded contractible domain $A\subset\mathbb R^{2n}$ with $\partial A$ smooth, such that $A$ is **not symplectomorphic** to a star shaped domain?

Thanks